# Can't find vgaswitcheroo directory in CentOS6

Tags: linux, centos, video

I've installed CentOS6 on my laptop, which has a built in VGA and a discrete (AMD) VGA.

I used to switch AMD video off in other distro's (e.g. Fedora, Arch) using:

```
$ echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Because when both are running my battery drains quickly and the temperature rises. However in CentOS I can't find the `vgaswitcheroo` folder under `/sys/kernel`.

How can I disable my AMD video device like I did before?

Here's my `lsmod | grep radeon` :

```
radeon                917108  0 
ttm                    80957  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         40087  2 i915,radeon
drm                   265638  5 i915,radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit            5935  2 i915,radeon
i2c_core               31084  7 videodev,i2c_i801,i915,radeon,drm_kms_helper,drm,i2c_algo_bit
```

And `lsmod | grep -i intel`:

```
snd_hda_intel          27823  4 
snd_hda_codec         121518  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_pcm                86635  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd                    69907  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_pcm,snd_timer
snd_page_alloc          8470  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
```

I have AMD Radeon 7670M VGA card so i have no idea whether if these are the right modules or not.

Here's `dmesg | grep -i switcheroo`:

```
VGA switcheroo: detected switching method \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.ATPX handle
vga_switcheroo: enabled
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this page is on the ArchLinux wiki there are still a couple of things on it that might be worth trying on your CentOS6 system.

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hybrid_graphics

This fedoraforums.org thread titled: [VGA switcheroo problem](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=252159) also had some good leads of things to try.

In general I would suspect that the absence of `vgaswitcheroo` has to do with a driver (kernel module) either being loaded or not loaded. I would confirm that you're using the correct drivers first. The reason I say this is because of this comment in that thread:

> So, the lesson of my story, if you can't see the vgaswitcheroo
>   directory, then perhaps one of the first things to check is whether
>   you actually have two video drivers loaded. lsmod is your friend.

Comment: I've edited my question to include `lsmod` result. Please take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @RafaelAdel - the intel drivers are for sound (I have the same ones). The radeon drivers looks right.

Comment: @RafaelAdel - can you please provide output to `lspci`?